What triggers a promise callback?
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('resolved');
});
p.then((r) => console.log(r));
console.log('hi!');

If you run this code here, you will see the output 'hi!' before 'resolved'. I take this to mean the promise callback is run after console.log('hi!'). Which means that it's probably not called in the promise constructor like this:
Promise(callback) {
    // setup promise
    callback(resolve, reject);
}

So then when IS callback called? What triggers it?

@Rory Not really much to do with "overhead". It's to do with when the task is scheduled to be run, not that it's slower because it has more to do or anything like that.

a promise is called async .. it means that the statement after p.then... will be invoked immediately without waiting for the promise to be resolved. For further readings Promise

Fair point, but callback will still be immediately invoked as soon as the Promise constructor is executed. I'll remove my previous comment to avoid inaccurate information

This behavior is due to JavaScript's event loop and its task queues (microtask and macrotask queues). The .then() method, being part of the microtask queue, is processed after the current script block finishes execution and before any pending tasks like timers or I/O operations. Thus, "hi!" is printed before "resolved".

@gib65 Are you asking about the callback passed to new Promise or about the callback passed to then?

@Tauqeer Nasir, I think this answers my question. So if I were to re-write the promise constructor, it would look more like this: Promise(callback){/*setup promise*/setTimeout(()=>callback(resolve,reject))}. The setTimeout would ensure the callback is run after the current script block is finished. @Bergi, I mean the callback passed to promise constructor.

@gib65 Yes. it will definitely run after the current block.

No, the callback passed into the promise constructor is executed synchronously.
